# Double modals and Double modal dialects

Tags: modal-verbs

As a second question linked to the [Future Pluperfect Tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/130279/future-pluperfect-tense) question.

Can we use double modals the way it is introduced in [this source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/455868?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)?

[image: The Future Pluperfect: Double Tenses in American English Auxiliaries]

Are the following sentences possible in modern English?

- **John might could examine the doctor.**
- **John might could have examined the doctor.**

Comment: The use of "might could" is a feature of some dialects of English, but it is not standard and should be avoided in most speaking and writing. Its use will give your communication a folksy, rural effect that most native speakers will find strange and possibly humorous coming from a non-native.

Comment: Agreed.  Although this might be fine with some English speakers, it sounds very strange to me.

Comment: Question has already been reviewed extensively on this site https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3211/is-might-could-a-correct-construct